# How can i make my program stop using a line after it has found a match?

Tags: python

i am trying to make a program for my computer science class that has us create a lottery game generator. this game has you input your number, then it creates tickets winning tickets to match to your ticket. so if you match 3, it says you matched 3, 4 says 4, 5 says 5 and at 6 matches it will stop the program. my problem is that if you got a match of 6 on this first randomly generated set (highly unlikely, but possible), it doesn't keep going until a match of 3, 4 and 5. i need it to match a set of 3, say so, then ignore matching another set of three and only worry about match 4, 5 and 6.

```
from random import *
import random

def draw():
        #return a list of six randomly picked numbers
        numbers=list(range(1,50))
        drawn=[]
        for n in range (6):
            x=randint(0,len(numbers)-1)
            no=numbers.pop(x)
            drawn.append(no)
        return drawn

a=int(input("What is your first number? (maximum of 49)"))
b=int(input("What is your second number? (different from 1)"))
c=int(input("What is your third number? (different from 1,2)"))
i=int(input("What is your fourth number?(different from 1,2,3)"))
e=int(input("What is your fith number?(different from 1,2,3,4)"))
f=int(input("What is your sixth number?(different from 1,2,3,4,5)"))

def winner():
    ticket=[a,b,c,i,e,f]
    wins=0
    costs=0
    while True:
        costs=costs+1
        d=draw()
        matches=0
        for h in ticket:
            if h in d:
                matches=matches+1
        if matches==3:
            print ("You Matched 3 on try", costs)
        elif matches==4:
            print ("Cool! 4 matches on try", costs)
        elif matches==5:
            print ("Amazing!", costs, "trys for 5 matches!")
        elif matches==6:
            print ("Congratulations! you matched all 6 numbers on try", costs)
            return False
draw()
winner()
```

one of my classmates made it have a while true statement for every matching pair, but this causes python to crash while finding each matching set. i have no other ideas on how to make the program stop from posting more than one match.

Comment: Note that the variable names `a`, `b` etc doesn't mean much to a user. And maybe you want a `largestMatchSoFar` variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint, sample

# Ontario Lotto 6/49 prize schedule
COST = 0.50
PRIZES = [0, 0, 0, 5., 50., 500., 1000000.]

def draw():
    return set(sample(range(1, 50), 6))

def get_ints(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return [int(i) for i in input(prompt).split()]
        except ValueError:
            pass

def pick():
    while True:
        nums = set(get_ints(
            "Please enter 6 numbers in [1..49], ie 3 4 17 22 44 47: "
        ))
        if len(nums) == 6 and 1 <= min(nums) and max(nums) <= 49:
            return nums

def num_matched(picked):
    return len(picked & draw())    # set intersection

def report(matches):
    total_cost = COST * sum(matches)
    total_won = sum(m*p for m,p in zip(matches, PRIZES))
    net = total_won - total_cost
    # report on the results:
    print("\nYou won:")
    print(
        "        nothing  {:>8} times   ->   ${:>12.2f}"
        .format(sum(matches[:3]), 0.)
    )
    for i in range(3, 7):
        print(
            "  ${:>12.2f}  {:>8} times   ->   ${:>12.2f}"
            .format(PRIZES[i], matches[i], PRIZES[i] * matches[i])
        )
    print(
        "\nYou paid ${:0.2f} to win ${:0.2f}, for a net result of ${:0.2f}."
        .format(total_cost, total_won, net)
    )

def main():
    # pick a set of numbers
    picked = pick()
    # repeat until we have seen 3, 4, 5, and 6-ball matches
    matches = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    while not all(matches[3:]):
        matches[num_matched(picked)] += 1
    report(matches)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which results in

```
Please enter 6 numbers in [1..49], ie 3 4 17 22 44 47: 4 6 9 12 14 19

You won:
        nothing  10060703 times   ->   $        0.00
  $        5.00    181218 times   ->   $   906090.00
  $       50.00      9888 times   ->   $   494400.00
  $      500.00       189 times   ->   $    94500.00
  $  1000000.00         1 times   ->   $  1000000.00

You paid $5125999.50 to win $2494990.00, for a net result of $-2631009.50.
```

Comment: Thank you so much Hugh, this code is more than perfect.

Answer (score 0):

just keep a record of what you have seen

```
...
costs=0
found = []
while True:
    ...
    if matches==3 and 3 not in found:
        found.append(3)
        print ("You Matched 3 on try", costs)
    elif matches==4 add 4 not in found:
        found.append(4)
        print ("Cool! 4 matches on try", costs)
    ...
    if set([3,4,5,6]).intersection(found) == set([3,4,5,6]):
        print "You Found em all!"
        return
```